# android printwriter of outputStream print data conversely

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, outputstream, printwriter

I have an android app that connect by bluetooth to a socket to bluetoothPrinter,
i create a print writer and write data into the printer, my problem is when i write arabic data its appears conversely , my code

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(
           new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(mmOutputStream, "8859_6")), true);


     String center = "\u001b\u0061\u0001";
     pw.println( center + "جمعية المبرات" );
```

So the text appears like this: تاربملا  ةيعمج

so how the printwriter send the data to the sockets? is there a solution?

Comment: sorry for asking is this working with ok in  English or some other language ?

Comment: yes it is working for english normally

Comment: read this http://jayason19.blogspot.in/2012/04/export-arabic-or-other-unicode.html may help you